# Specify a mixed effect model for per patient treatment effect and interactors for such effect

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, model

I have a study design setting where each patient received a treatment and was assed again after 30 days. the dependent variables are a set of symptoms and clinical values.

I thought of a design where the scores of such symptoms are evaluated before and after treatment for each patient.

Since all patients received the treatment I don't think that using the other variables as covariates makes sense causally. But instead I suppose it would be interesting to evaluate if and how other variables could influence the effect of the treatment.

So these are the questions:

- Should I consider the other covariates only as interacting with the treatmente (R notation: `output ~ treatment + treatment:covariate_1 + ... + treatment:covariate_n`), or also as independent variables (R notation: `output ~ treatment + treatment*covariate_1 + ... + treatment*covariate_n`)?
- As a random effect I would of course the subject (R lme4 notation: `... + (1 | subject)`)
- Should I include a random slope? if yes which factor should I consider for the random slope? the treatment (R lme4 notation: `... + (1 + treatment | subject)`)

Comment: If you have only two obervartions per cluster (the patient's score before and after the treatment), a mixed model won't work - you cannot estimate the residual variance: `set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), ID = rep(1:50, each = 2)); library(lme4); mod <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 + x|ID), data = df)`.

Comment: Isn't mixed effect models the standard for regression with paired data? Furthermore you also included a random slope. why?

Comment: I made the test and the problem is with the random slope. the random intercept seems ok.

Comment: could you explain me (not in math term but as interpretation) why a random slope won't work with two time point?

Comment: Imagine fitting a OLS model on two data points. Then you could find a beta0 and beta1 that exactly hit both observations. But this would mean that there is no random deviation from the regression line (like it is said in the model equation).